# HTML DOM: Checking if Cell Exists with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, cell

Every row has a `deleteCell` and `insertCell` method. But how do I see whether a cell *exists* in the first place?

(A cell may have been deleted by combining it with another cell through `rowSpan`, and I would like to know if my cell was deleted.)

Comment: Do the cells have unique ids?

Comment: Do you have a reference to this cell, or just the row?

Comment: @Dan: Lol, no, that would've been trivial. @Conor: No idea -- what does the "length" of a cell mean? @Matt: I have the row and the cell index (so I have a reference to the cell object itself, yes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `HTMLTableRowElement` has a `cells` collection, full of `HTMLTableDataCellElement` objects.

To find out which cells are missing AFAIK you'll need to iterate through that collection, ensuring that you read the `colSpan` property of each entry to find out the nominal column number of the *next* entry.

Comment: Ah I see... so it doesn't keep track of every cell, it literally deletes it. Thanks.

Comment: @Merhdad yup, there's no extra `<td>` put in the DOM if the previous cell uses a `colspan`.